# PDO won't update to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to update the value of a field in MySQL with PDO, i've tried with the different types of prepared statements but none of them worked.
Here is my code:

```
    $table = $_POST['table'];
    $field = $_POST['field'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];

    try{

       $available = "Available";
       $cero = 0;

       $q = "UPDATE ? SET $available = $cero WHERE ? = ? ";
       $stmt = $connection->getPdo()->prepare($q);  
       $stmt->execute( array ($table,$field,$value) );

       echo true;       

    }catch(PDOException $exception){
      echo $exception;
    }
```

Problem Solved:

```
   $q = "UPDATE $table SET $available = $cero WHERE $field = ? ";
   $stmt = $connection->getPdo()->prepare($q);  
   $stmt->execute( array ($value) );
```

Comment: "*none of them worked*" is not a valid error message. You need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Can you use a bound parameter for the name of a table?

Comment: Ah, I'm glad it wasn't just something that everyone else knew about but I'd somehow managed to overlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `?` to substitute a table name, or indeed any object name (columns, databases etc) in a prepared query. Parameterisation only works for values. You will have to do:

```
$q = "UPDATE $table SET $available = $cero WHERE $field = ? ";
$stmt = $connection->getPdo()->prepare($q);  
$stmt->execute( array ($value) );
```

The very fact that you tried to do this suggests that you are getting the table name from user input, which is a *very* bad idea, even if you are escaping it.

Comment: It's not necessarily unsafe. There could be some internal decision process the script uses to decide which table to update, and the OP just wants to write a generalizable query rather than a separate one for each table. I agree that taking unvalidated user input for the table name is a bad idea...

Comment: Thank you so much, i also had to replace the '?' after the 'WHERE' clause.

Comment: Thanks to DaveRandom for your feedback, the final query came up as:

    $q = "UPDATE $table SET $available = $cero WHERE $field = ? ";
    $stmt = $connection->getPdo()->prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute( array ($value) );

Comment: @IsaacGonzalez Yes a realised that mistake about 30 seconds after I got in the car and started driving, I'm glad you realised and understood what I meant :-D